# Issue while setting width = 100% on a button

Tags: html, css

Actually i'm trying to set the button width equals to the input width but at 100% it doesn't getting the same width and i can't get why.

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

input,
button {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.main-div {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-div input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-div button {
  display: block;
  background: #00a2ff;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <h3>Fatturazione Elettronica</h3>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." />
  <button>Login</button>
</div>
```

Actually i've tried to play even with the margin and padding but still getting the same output.

Comment: Provide your html too please

Comment: @MartinBA there is nothing special just this in the body "   <div class="main-div">
        <h3>Fatturazione Elettronica</h3>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email..."/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password..."/>
        <button>Login</button>
    </div>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button *is* `100%` width, but your inputs are `100% + 30px` width. It comes down to `input` elements and `button` elements not having the same default value for their CSS [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property.

`<button>`s by default have `box-sizing: border-box` applied. This means that padding is applied *inward* instead of outward. If you give an item a width of `500px`, padding of `15px`, and `box-sizing: border-box`, the width will remain `500px`.

However, `<input>` elements (and *most* elements) are `box-sizing: content-box`, which means padding will **add** to their width. That same `500px` width, `15px` padding element will instead have a width of `530px` (assuming the padding is applied to both the left and right sides).

The solution is to make them consistent. Either add `box-sizing: border-box` to your inputs (as I have below), or set your `button` to `box-sizing: content-box`.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

input,
button {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.main-div {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-div input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-div button {
  display: block;
  background: #00a2ff;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <h3>Fatturazione Elettronica</h3>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." />
  <button>Login</button>
</div>
```

Comment: greate solution thank you, and thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `box-sizing : border-box;` property on the input fields, [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) you will find information about it!

```
input[type=email],
input[type=password] {
    box-sizing : border-box;
}
```

Let me know if that helps! [Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/pQNwpK) is a link to codepen if you want to check it!

Answer (score 2):

Actually CSS is applying right on the content. See this screenshot of chrome inspector.

[image]

So what is happening is the padding applied to the input is extending input besides width of 20%, making it appear that button width is not 100%.

So to avoid this kind of situation you can use `box-sizing` property.
You can read about `box-sizing` on MDN.
[box-sizing-mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```